# Codewars execution timeout despite short execution time on other IDEs (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I was solving a [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsgeb.png) on CodeWars and my solution keeps getting execution timeouts. I know the code is correct and doesn't take long to execute, since when I plugged the same code and tests into the IDE Atom, it only took 0.117s to execute.

The goal of the task is to create a function for e.g. "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a" --> "Thi1s is2 3a T4est".

Is it a problem with CodeWars or is there something I am missing?

Thanks for the help.

```
def order(sentence):
    new_list =[]
    order = 1
    sentence = sentence.split(' ')
    while len(new_list) < len(sentence):
        for c, x in enumerate(sentence):
            
            try: 
                x.index(str(order))
                print(c)
                order += 1
                new_list.append(sentence[c])
            except:
                continue
    return ' '.join(new_list)
```

Comment: When you submit an answer on CodeWars, it goes through a lot more test cases than what you see in the example test cases section. The most likely cause is that you're code is too slow for some of the longer test cases since your code isn't as efficent as it can be

Comment: Read the section in the screenshot of "Why did my code time out?"

Comment: @Samathingamajig Nah, it already times out on one of those three example cases.

Comment: @KellyBundy Exactly, there is no way the code takes that long to execute for only 3 sample tests. Could you think of a possible reason?

Comment: You'd quickly find out if you debug with the test it fails.

Comment: could it be that the examples don't cover two-digit numbers, but the hidden tests do? it looks like you easily get stuck in a loop there.

Answer (score 1):

I think was is happening is that they test an empty string which causes an infinite loop in your code or words without any number.
You can try it yourself:

```py
print(order(""))
print(order("this"))
```

To fix the former, you can use this

```py
if (not sentence.strip())
    return ""
```

What you might also be looking for is something to sort the list by custom order. Luckily Python provides the `sorted` method and all you need to do is implement a method that accepts a string and returns an integer.

Please note that I did not handle malign cases of words without any numbers inside, as they are not specified in the exercise.

```py
import re

def find_index(s):
    match = re.search("\d+", s)
    return int(match.group(0))

def order(sentence):
    if (not sentence.strip())
      return ""
    sentence = sentence.split(' ')
    return ' '.join(sorted(sentence, key=lambda x: find_index(x)))

print(order("is2 Thi10s T4est 3a")) # returns "is2 3a T4st Thi10s"
```

Bonus: this will work also with numbers larger than 9 as demonstrated. Apparently, this is not part of the exercise though.

Comment: [The problem](https://www.codewars.com/kata/your-order-please) is accessible, you can read the description and also test there yourself.

Comment: `If the input string is empty, return an empty string.` - OP needs to cover this. I guess making it work with longer sentences is just a bonus.